# What would a valid YAML header look like in for a bookdown file in Rstudio

Tags: yaml, rstudio, bookdown

I am new to the bookdown package and am getting this error;

```
"Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : 
  Parser error: while parsing a block mapping at line 1, column 1 did not find expected key at line 2, column 14
Calls: <Anonymous> ... setNames -> resolve -> <Anonymous> -> yaml_load -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted"
```

I have put my header into YAML validators and it seems as if its a valid header. This is my header;

```
title: "A Baseline Examination of the Stream Health"
author: "Authors"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output: bookdown::gitbook
documentclass: book
bibliography:
  - book.bib
  - packages.bib
biblio-style: apalike
link-citations: yes
github-repo: rstudio/bookdown-demo
description: "Discription"
```

I have tried putting the YAML header in a YAML validator, this said that the YAML header was valid.

Comment: The YAML is indeed valid but maybe your YAML implementation is too stupid to read it. Try putting `bookdown::bookdown_site` and `bookdown::gitbook` in quotes so that the contained colons are not mistaken for value markers.